# Showing a bipartite graph has a perfect matching with given number of neighbors

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G=(L\cup R,E)$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ nodes on each side. Find the upper bound on $n$ such that if any 2 vertices in $L$ have at-least 2 neighbors in $R$, Then $G$ has a perfect matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false for $n\geq 5$. Pick two vertices $l,l'$ in $L$ and two vertices $r,r'$ in $R$. Consider the bipartite graph in which the only edges which exist are those which have at least one of $l,l',r$ or $r'$ as a vertex.

There is no perfect matching as at most $4$ edges can belong to the matching.

Example for $n=5$:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I missed something in the question. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You basically answered the question including what I have missed.

Comment: I can look into the future ;)

Comment: @JorgeFernández I cam across some of your bipartite matching posts. I was wondering if we could chat offline? My mail is gsaxena888...<and the rest is standard gmaaill suffix etc.)

Comment: Sure no problem, my mail is jorgefernandez at ciencias.unam.mx